# Как сделать анимацию загрузки в зависимости от времени загрузки?

Tags: javascript

Есть блок, внутри лоадер. Например время 1 минута и 3 секунды = 63 секунды. Ширина лоадера может так же быть разной, например 500 пикселей. Так вот сколько пикселей надо прибавлять каждую секунду к ширине лоадера, чтобы за 63 секунды он полностью заполнился??

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .content {
            padding-top: 40px;
        }

        .block {
            position: relative;
            width: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            height: 5px;
            background: #dadada;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .block-inner {
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            background: green;
            width: 0;
            transition: all .3s ease;
        }

        #play {
            display: block;
            margin: 10px auto;
        }

        .time-wrapper {
            text-align: center;
            width: auto;
            margin: 10px auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="block" id="block">
            <div id="loader" class="block-inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="time">
            <div class="time-wrapper">
                <span id="minutes"></span>m:
                <span id="seconds"></span>s
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button-set">
            <button id="play">Play</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        "use strict";

        window.onload = function() {
            var 
                minutes      = 2,
                seconds      = 0,
                block        = document.getElementById('block'),
                loader       = document.getElementById('loader'),
                blockWidth   = block.offsetWidth,
                play         = document.getElementById('play'),
                minutesBlock = document.getElementById('minutes'),
                secondsBlock = document.getElementById('seconds'),
                perSeconds   = (minutes * 60) + seconds,
                percentage   = (blockWidth / 100) / (perSeconds / 100);

            minutesBlock.innerHTML = minutes;
            secondsBlock.innerHTML = seconds;

            console.log('perSeconds = ' + perSeconds);
            console.log('persentage = ' + percentage);

            play.onclick = function() {
                var percent = 0;
                var isPlaying = setInterval(function() {
                    if (minutes === 0 && seconds === 0) {
                        clearInterval(isPlaying);
                    } else {
                        if (seconds === 0) {
                            minutes--;
                            minutesBlock.innerHTML = minutes;
                            seconds = 60;
                        }

                        seconds--;
                        percent += percentage;
                        loader.style.width = percent + 'px';
                        secondsBlock.innerHTML = seconds;

                        if (seconds === 0 && minutes !== 0) {
                            seconds = 59;
                            secondsBlock.innerHTML = seconds;
                            minutes--;
                            minutesBlock.innerHTML = minutes;
                        }
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот так пробовал, вроде работает но иногда не хватает несколько пикселей. Для одной минуты заполняет всю полосу, а для 2-х немного остается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var iter = 0;
...
var isPlaying = setInterval(function() {
  ...
  loader.style.width = (++iter * blockWidth / perSeconds) + 'px';
```

Comment: не работает((((

Comment: @undefined Вы неправильно скопировали к себе мой код.

Comment: да, действительно, прошу прощения, все работает, спасибо.